# GWT Super Dev Mode Incremental Compilation doesnt work

Tags: gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I use gwt 2.6.1. I've would like to use Super Dev Mode.
I normally run with RMB on project, then I select Run Super Dev Mode.

My app is huge, so it takes time to compile, and finally when it is done I am making small change in gwt client code, I refresh web page, and nothing happend. Application have same view/behavior like before this change. 
Only stopping Super Dev Mode and starting it again makes changes visible, but it takes so much time (cause it recompile from scratch).
Please help me, how can I use incremental compillation in gwt.

I've already added:
`<add-linker name="xsiframe"/>`
to my *.gwt.xml file.

please help.

Comment: Have you tried to update to 2.7? There were a lot improvements regarding SDM.

Comment: I have complex application, so It is not easy. In my other app in 2.7 there is no problem with incremental compilation. I wonder is this even works for 2.6.1?

Comment: What's the reason that you can't move to GWT 2.7.0